# Microphone amplifier with opamp doubts

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am reading a following [Application Note](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf) about microphone amplifiers:

Here is the circuit:
[image: Circuit]

At some point author says following:

> Resistor R1 and capacitor C3 form a high-pass filter. The corner frequency of this filter must be low
>   enough to not attenuate low-frequency sound waves. A 5Hz corner frequency is used to calculate the
>   value of C3:

How can R1 and C3 be HP filter since ac input impedance of the OPAMP circuit is impedance of C3 which is said to have high capacitance value. Even if we consider FET as a current generator in ac modus, it will see on the drain R||Zc which is LP filter.

Comment: One issue with this circuit to keep in mind is that Vcc needs to be noise free, otherwise the power supply noise is amplified R2/R1 times. Some degree of flexibility is possible by making VCC higher, so that R1 is larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input impedance of the op-amp is zero, courtesy of R2 and C2, and its huge open loop gain. It's called a virtual ground input.

The output current of the microphone sees two impedances in parallel, R1 to AC ground (VCC), and C3 to AC ground (op-amp virtual ground). Its output current will split between them according to the ratio of their impedances. At very low frequencies, all the signal will go into R1, as C3 is very high impedance. At higher freuqencies, as C3 becomes lower impedance, all the current goes through C3.